# Анти-социал-демократический / антисоциалдемократический

Tags: орфография, приставка, слитно-дефис, правила, сложные-слова

Розенталь пишет, что, прибавляя приставку к прилагательному, через дефис пишущемуся, мы всё слитно пишем: ***антисоциалдемократический*** (перед 7-м пунктом: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80).
Но в РАН написано, что, прибавляя приставку к слову, через дефис которое пишется, мы снова дефис пишем: ***анти-социал-демократический*** (http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80). Кому верить?
А как писать: *без-хот-договый* или *бес-хот-договый*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Русский орфографический словарь: анти-социал-демократия, **анти-социал-демократический.**
2. Прилагательное  **сохраняет** форму написания  существительного, способ образования: суффиксальный (суффикс -***ЧЕСК***).

**Сравнить**: *контрреволюция — контрреволюционный, контр-адмирал — контр-адмиральский.*

3. **Разное решение** у Розенталя и в ПАС связано, вероятно, с разными **схемами** словообразования. Розенталь считает, что здесь суффиксально-префиксальный способ, а в ПАС —  суффиксальный способ.
4. Хот-дог — ***бесхотдоговый***, способ образования **суффиксально-префиксальный**, поэтому здесь слитное написание.

Comment: Добрый вечер, *Sharon*. Мне кажется, что в слове *дем/о/крат/ическ/ий* суффикс -ИЧЕСК- (как в словах *дем/о/граф/ическ/ий*, *демон/ическ/ий*, *псих/ическ/ий*).

Comment: Спасибо, но  я все-таки думаю, что здесь суффикс -ЧЕСК-, так как в основе есть И, а в "демонический" суффикс  -ИЧЕСК-, там нет И. Суффиксы  можно посмотреть у Ефремовой  https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136576/ческ  https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136242/ическ

Comment: Как эти способы отличить?

Comment: При разных способах использованы разные исходные существительные: социал-демократия и анти- социал-демократия. Возможно, раньше не было слова анти- социал-демократия, а сейчас оно нормировано. Поэтому надо смотреть форму исходного существительного.

Comment: ИРЯ (§ 632): «Морф ***-ическ-***... выступает после парно-мягких согласных: *эпизодический, циклический, сценический, типический, героический, хореический*, в том числе после основ сущ. с суф. *-ист (коммунистический, реалистический)*, сущ. на *-лог, -граф, -метр, -скоп, **-крат** (идеологический, хореографический, хронометрический, стереоскопический, **демократический**)*». (https://rusgram.narod.ru/609-645.html) У Тихонова то же: *дем/о/крат/и'ческ/ий* (https://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-d.htm)

Comment: Может, и так, но в данном случае это несущественно. Надо смотреть словообразовательную схему (что усекается и т.д.), отдельный вопрос.